# Xcode include path not recognising header files

Tags: c, xcode, clang, glfw

I am trying to work with GLFW and OpenGL in C but have come across an issue whereby trying to include the headers I downloaded does not work despite the headers being in my header include path -

[image: ./Vendor being recursively included in the header search path]

Here are all the paths I have tried - and I have added -I./Vendor/glfw/include/GLFW/ to the C compiler too

[image: A bunch of broken include paths]

(Many aren't underlined in red since I have (apparently) disabled squiggles)

The only way I can get the code to build is by using `#include "/Users/[MyUser]/Documents/dev/CGL/CGL/Vendor/glfw/include/GLFW/glfw3.h"` which only causes linking errors

If anyone knows how to fix this problem or knows a setting I could fix I would much appreciate it

I am using the latest Clang compiler on macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current working directory when Xcode is building is not the directory where your sources are, so `.` is not the correct start for a path to files in the source tree.

Xcode defines a symbol, `SRCROOT`, that contains the path to the source tree. Change the include search path setting to `$(SRCROOT)/Vendor`.

Comment: That still doesn't work unfortunately - I have set the include headers path to $(SRCROOT)/Include/** (Recursive) which contains the GLFW, GLAD and KHR header file folders (that path would be GLFW/glfw3.h for example) however Xcode still states that it cannot find the files with angle brackets or quotes. Any suggestions?

Comment: I know that it doesn't expand those characters - Xcode automatically adds ** to indicate a recursive search within the directories

Comment: @TTG: Okay, so the problem is likely you have to get the path right, using something like `$(SRCROOT)/glfw/include` rather than `$(SRCROOT)/include`.

Comment: I have verified that I have the correct path since, when Xcode expands $(SRCROOT) into an absolute path I can copy it into finder and it will direct me to the file on the filesystem